# What could someone do with Hydrokinesis (the ability to control water with your mind)?

Tags: science-based, super-powers, water, ice

Someone has the ability to manipulate and shape water from any source. They cannot create water from nothing, but they can control it at a molecular level. For example, they can change the properties of water by speeding up or slowing down the water molecules, and if they gather enough water, they can use it to hit their enemies by forming it into weapons. They could also control some of the weather, as clouds are made up of water. The only limitations are that it takes physical effort to gather large amounts of water, and the more they use their ability, the more exhausted they become. It also becomes much more difficult to control water from further away. For example, they cannot pull water from a pond 10 miles away without significant effort. However, the more they train, the better they get- like exercising.

What would be some additional ways they could use this ability?

Comment: It's generally a good idea when making a magic power to try using it to blow up your plot, then work backwards from there to restrict it.

Comment: it would be great for party tricks

Comment: One thing I've thought of is the removal of water from a certain object. For example, they could remove the water from a person, effectively mummifying them.

Comment: HivElaura, be aware that Stack-exchange deals poorly with questions which are not focusing on specific problems. You should here at the very least give a domain to use your power in, as right now making your yorkshire tea from the comfort of your sofa is an equivalent answer to smash people with a water whip, Avatar style ^^. You can learn more about the site rules in the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and help-center ([here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [there](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What can't they do?

Power over water is one of the strongest forms you can imagine.

First of all, organisms are composed of and contain water. You can block a bloodstream, pull it out of the person and more. Anyone against you will lose consciousness practically immediately, with death shortly after if the water mage so wishes.

### Huge effects

Water magic can be used for absolutely **huge** effects. You can water crops or dehydrate them by raising or lowering the groundwater level. Not to mention you can use it for erosion, removing the fertile layer of a field by rushing the water past after you dehydrated it a while.

You can accelerate and decelerate the groundwater for eroding or softening effects. This way you can move earth, causing landslides or sinkholes. This can be done underground, without visible signs. You can destroy buildings and if the area permits it whole villages if you're patient enough. You can let it settle in stones and buildings to freeze or boil, using its properties of expansion to crack or destroy concrete or warp and rust metals.

You can also use it to create, letting the water drag materials to a place where you'll force it into the ground, so it leaves behind some sediment and possibly stones. You can waylay rivers by making and destroying dams, with all the resulting effects. Depending on the powers this can cost a week or a few months, but that a single person can do this seems incredibly powerful to me. Try that with fire magic.

There's probably plenty more. I've mostly talked about ground water, as it seems control over that is more powerful than a rainstorm. It is more localised and better to control.

### Subtle

There is a new way to administer vaccinations. It is still in development, but a fluid is 'shot' through a thin opening, able to pierce the skin and enter the body with leaving no humanly visible mark. Drug people, poison them, feed them important minerals... you can do a lot here. Water can also permeate many apparatus. You could use moisture, possibly something non reactive to keep internals safe, to enter something. From there you can use the fluid to open, cut, move or bridge electronics for all manner of effects. Repair or destroy. It can do whatever you need.

### Conclusion

These are just a few things from the top of my head. There's a million applications, big and small, for which you can use this. Even with little power you can kill people or destroy buildings, though sometimes it'll take a while. The fact is that you can, and it can be hard to spot and stop many effects of a water mage. If applied correctly, I think the water mage is the most powerful in all walks of life. Both in fast-paced situations and long term projects.

Comment: Some of these may require being able to see exactly where the water is going, though if the user has the ability to perceive where exactly each molecule under their control is they could "take pictures" by shooting water molecules and sensing where they bounce.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with the obvious - they can kill (or puppet) people directly by manipulating the water in their bodies, at least without carving out some no-using-directly-on-people exception. Acceleration and range limits are another thing to add here, as relativistic or supersonic anything can do a lot of damage, and purely from a dramatic perspective "instant kill anything I want within line of sight" is boring.

Less obviously, and one I don't recall having seen on other explorations of this - water is a polar molecule, and your hydrokinetic could in theory [magnetize it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37554/can-water-be-magnetized) since they have molecular-level control.

Comment: Perhaps the water could have a certain purity requirement. On your latter point, do you mean forcibly manipulating each water molecule to align?

edit: By "from any source" I am going to assume from any significant source of water (ocean and groundwater included). Since those are not exactly pure, it moots my first idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding properly, this is essentially Waterbending from the Avatar: The Last Airbender series. The concept is explored in great detail there, and as for "surprising uses", there is an instance of a waterbender puppeteering a human since humans are primarily water.

Comment: I would like to know why someone downvoted this, he is right, this topic is so well known and though of just in both avatar and any other show where they control water, hell even pokemon who manipulate water have some weird effects

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t - simply referencing an outside work is not typically recommended for an answer - greater context should be provided.

Comment: We agree on that, but factually, it is a correct answer and does anwser the question, its low effort tho.